# Oracle-MAF Qr-Code Scanner Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.0.0, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner, oracle-maf

i'm trying to use (BarcodeDemo) from Oracle JDeveloper - under the `jdev_install/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/Samples` directory.

it was working fine before month ago, right now i faced exception it seems some plugin updated anyway i download latest version of [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner).

So it compiling but in deployment log i faced below issue:

Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.0.0, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0

[maf-application.xml - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npg5C.png)

So, how can i upgrade engine of cordova-android in jdeveloper

Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With maf 2.5.1 and plugin 6.0.6 it will work with sdk 27 installed only if you put to build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```